# Configuring Cookie in IIS 8.5

Tags: web, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, iis-8.5

Is it possible to set a cookie in `IIS`?

Assuming a web system that provides web document edit; clients use installed MS Office applications and open an office file in the `IIS` folder via HTTP as **WebDAV**, Office sends `OPTIONS/HEAD` requests to the **WebDAV** folder.

This authentication can be processed by `BASIC/NTLM`. When the authentication finished successfully, I would like to do `set-cookie`.

Comment: "When the authentication finished successfully, I would like to do set-cookie", then you have to write your own IIS extension to do so.

Comment: Lex, I searched for what IIS extension is and it looks like to the point. Thanks!